# Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication

Tags: java, android, vuforia

I've got this error and tried some solutions I found here but they didn't work.

I don't know why and how to solve this.
Please help.

Android Studio 2.1.2

```
07-12 18:28:46.742 642-642/com.vuforia.samples.VuforiaSamples E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vuforia.samples.VuforiaSamples, PID: 642
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vuforia.samples.VuforiaSamples-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.vuforia.samples.VuforiaSamples-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.vuforia.samples.VuforiaSamples-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:676)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1861)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vuforia.samples.VuforiaSamples-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.vuforia.samples.VuforiaSamples-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.vuforia.samples.VuforiaSamples-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1004)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:666)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6294)        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:222) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1861) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 

Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    ... 12 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Comment: Include the manifest

Answer (score 8):

After a few search i came up this sollution,
Its because of the android studio tries to instant run.
to turn off this feature

- Go to file
- click setting
- select Build,Execution development on left
- side menu  disable instant run to hotswap by unchecking it.
- select apply and its all done

[image]

setting Secreenshot for reference. Thanks hopefully it may help you.